# iOS5 Pages like view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, view

is in iOS5 a particular view for a "Pages" style?
Is there a certain control/UI element which I could use? I do not need the preview mode of a document, just an image and a text below it which come from an NSArray or something like similar...

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html). It's the sample of Apple that will provide pretty much the same interface as you want.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

We use Gridviews for this - See the above mentioned [AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Custom `UItableview`. It would give you effect like grid view.